# SpatialPolygonDataFrame plotting using ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, gis, shapefile, r-maptools

I have a shape file for the greater London area. I use the `readShapePoly` function from the `maptools` package to load it in R as a `SpatialPolygonDataFrame` .

I want to the plot those polygons .. Which I have already done by using the basic of `plot` function in R.
The output looks as shown in this image:

[image: plot of London]

Now, I am trying to plot the same shape file using `ggplot2` but it doesn't work for me.
I am getting some weird lines in the graph as shown below:
[image: ggplot2 of London]

The code I used was :

```
london.wards <- readShapePoly("~/TD/london_wards2013/london_wards2013.shp"
                          , proj4string=CRS(projString))
wards.count <- nrow(london.wards@data)
# assign id for each lsoa

london.wards@data$id <- 1:wards.count
wards.fort <- fortify(london.wards, region='id')
ggplot(wards.fort, aes(long, lat)) + geom_polygon(colour='black', fill='white')
```

where projString is the projection string describing the projection used for the input shape file.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to add an additional aesthetic, `group`. Assuming the polygon id is called `ID`, the synatx will look like:

```
ggplot(wards.fort, aes(x = long, y = lat, group = ID)) + 
   geom_polygon(colour='black', fill='white')
```

Answer (score 13):

Alternatively, is good to transition to the [sf](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sf/index.html) package which is integrated nicely with `ggplot2` via the `geom_sf` geometry.

```r
library(sf)
library(ggplot2)

# Download the London shapefile.
# Links at Statistical GIS Boundary Files for London:
# https://data.london.gov.uk/dataset/statistical-gis-boundary-files-london
dataset_url <- "https://data.london.gov.uk/download/statistical-gis-boundary-files-london/b381c92b-9120-45c6-b97e-0f7adc567dd2/London-wards-2014.zip"
download.file(dataset_url, destfile = "London-wards-2014.zip")
unzip("London-wards-2014.zip", exdir = "London-wards-2014")

# Read the shapefile
polys <- st_read("./London-wards-2014/London-wards-2014 (1)/London-wards-2014_ESRI/London_Ward.shp")
#> Reading layer `London_Ward' from data source `~\London-wards-2014\London-wards-2014 (1)\London-wards-2014_ESRI\London_Ward.shp' using driver `ESRI Shapefile'
#> Simple feature collection with 654 features and 7 fields
#> geometry type:  POLYGON
#> dimension:      XY
#> bbox:           xmin: 503568.2 ymin: 155850.8 xmax: 561957.5 ymax: 200933.9
#> epsg (SRID):    NA
#> proj4string:    +proj=tmerc +lat_0=49 +lon_0=-2 +k=0.999601272 +x_0=400000 +y_0=-100000 +datum=OSGB36 +units=m +no_defs

# Fast plot/map
ggplot(polys) +
  geom_sf()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-05-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>