# ggmap border line Issue

Tags: r, border, ggmap

I am trying to create a map that to show some study sites in three states. I would like to get rid of the black border lines that go through the map. Like below:

[image: Map with plotted Study sites. Black state borders cutting through map]

```
lon <- c(-89.105917,-89.377778,-86.700278,-86.677361,-87.338083,-87.340444)
lat <- c(37.358694, 37.215278,38.460528,38.448389,37.594583,37.5945)
#crop
lon1 <- c(-86.6214142,-87.3423767,-87.6656265,-87.1565475,-87.8155823,-87.3194199,-87.3565598)
lat1 <- c(38.484581,37.7038918,37.7400513,38.0794983,37.6372185,37.4466667,37.3590546)
#CRP
lon2 <-c(-88.4263,-87.4707718,-86.435585,-87.9516907,-89.2439117,-88.3630524,-89.0109711)
lat2 <- c(37.3582993,37.5196114,37.5220261,37.4958801,37.3413811,37.2275009,37.3633308)
#Forest
lon3 <-c(-86.608551,-87.3794403,-88.9937515,-86.7436066,-86.7483826)
lat3 <- c(38.2506294,36.9505539,37.4111404,38.1277695,37.1684914)
#Pasture
lon4 <-c(-86.6036377,-86.2461395,-86.9746704,-87.4977493,-88.9970474,-86.2609634,-86.6067734,-86.9820709)
lat4 <- c(37.0606689,37.8114433,37.5391922,37.8073006,37.4703789,37.3089409,38.1600189,37.6018295)

df <- as.data.frame(cbind(lon,lat))
df1 <- as.data.frame(cbind(lon1,lat1))
df2 <- as.data.frame(cbind(lon2,lat2))
df3 <- as.data.frame(cbind(lon3,lat3))
df4 <- as.data.frame(cbind(lon4,lat4))


pdf("/Users/tribaker/Desktop/Thesis/RaCA/RaCASites.pdf")
al1 = get_map(location = c("posey county,indiana"), 
              zoom = 8, maptype = 'satellite')
mdat <- map_data('state',Fill=TRUE)
ggmap(al1) + 
  geom_path(data=mdat,aes(x=long,y=lat, regions=c('"Kentucky","Illinois","Indiana"')),colour="black",alpha=1)+
  borders("county", colour="grey60", alpha=.5)+
  borders("state", colour="black", alpha=.8)+
  geom_point(data = df, aes(x = lon, y = lat,colour = "Study Site", alpha = 0.8), size = 8, shape = 15) +
  geom_point(data = df1, aes(x = lon1, y = lat1,colour = "Crop",fill=TRUE, alpha = 0.8), size = 8, shape = 16) +
  geom_point(data = df2, aes(x = lon2, y = lat2,colour = "CRP", fill = TRUE ,alpha = 0.8), size = 8, shape = 16) +
  geom_point(data = df3, aes(x = lon3, y = lat3, colour = "Forest",fill = TRUE,alpha = 0.8), size = 8, shape =16) +
  geom_point(data = df4, aes(x = lon4, y = lat4,colour = "Pasture",fill = TRUE,alpha = 0.8), size = 8, shape = 16) +
  guides(fill=FALSE, alpha=FALSE, size=FALSE)
  geom_text(aes(label = state), data = mdat, size = 2, angle = 45)
```

thanks in advance

Comment: You may have to do a custom style on the base layer map. Google and ggmap make it fairly painless. I wrote a tutorial on it here... http://www.r-bloggers.com/creating-styled-google-maps-in-ggmap/

Comment: It looks like you are drawing those lines yourself... and they don't come from google. Did you try removing `borders("state", colour="black", alpha=.8)+`?

Comment: Yeah, can remove them but I would like to have them to show the borders of the states

Comment: What are you trying to remove then?

Comment: Sorry If I was not clear I am trying to removed the straight black lines that dissect the map.

Comment: A missing group aesthetic can lead to weird lines in shapefile data. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18174703/spatialpolygondataframe-plotting-using-ggplot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't get the `borders` function to work correctly, but you can just do it manually...

Create an `mdat2` dataframe with the county data and draw the borders yourself...

```
lon <- c(-89.105917,-89.377778,-86.700278,-86.677361,-87.338083,-87.340444)
lat <- c(37.358694, 37.215278,38.460528,38.448389,37.594583,37.5945)
#crop
lon1 <- c(-86.6214142,-87.3423767,-87.6656265,-87.1565475,-87.8155823,-87.3194199,-87.3565598)
lat1 <- c(38.484581,37.7038918,37.7400513,38.0794983,37.6372185,37.4466667,37.3590546)
#CRP
lon2 <-c(-88.4263,-87.4707718,-86.435585,-87.9516907,-89.2439117,-88.3630524,-89.0109711)
lat2 <- c(37.3582993,37.5196114,37.5220261,37.4958801,37.3413811,37.2275009,37.3633308)
#Forest
lon3 <-c(-86.608551,-87.3794403,-88.9937515,-86.7436066,-86.7483826)
lat3 <- c(38.2506294,36.9505539,37.4111404,38.1277695,37.1684914)
#Pasture
lon4 <-c(-86.6036377,-86.2461395,-86.9746704,-87.4977493,-88.9970474,-86.2609634,-86.6067734,-86.9820709)
lat4 <- c(37.0606689,37.8114433,37.5391922,37.8073006,37.4703789,37.3089409,38.1600189,37.6018295)

df <- as.data.frame(cbind(lon,lat))
df1 <- as.data.frame(cbind(lon1,lat1))
df2 <- as.data.frame(cbind(lon2,lat2))
df3 <- as.data.frame(cbind(lon3,lat3))
df4 <- as.data.frame(cbind(lon4,lat4))    

al1 = get_map(location = c("posey county,indiana"), 
              zoom = 8, maptype = 'satellite')
mdat <- map_data('state', regions=c("Kentucky","Illinois","Indiana"))
mdat2 <- map_data('county', regions=c("Kentucky","Illinois","Indiana"))

ggmap(al1) + 
  geom_path(data=mdat2,aes(x=long,y=lat,group=group), colour="grey60", alpha=.5)+
  geom_path(data=mdat,aes(x=long,y=lat,group=group), colour="black", alpha=.8)+
  geom_point(data = df, aes(x = lon, y = lat,colour = "Study Site", alpha = 0.8), size = 8, shape = 15) +
  geom_point(data = df1, aes(x = lon1, y = lat1,colour = "Crop",fill=TRUE, alpha = 0.8), size = 8, shape = 16) +
  geom_point(data = df2, aes(x = lon2, y = lat2,colour = "CRP", fill = TRUE ,alpha = 0.8), size = 8, shape = 16) +
  geom_point(data = df3, aes(x = lon3, y = lat3, colour = "Forest",fill = TRUE,alpha = 0.8), size = 8, shape =16) +
  geom_point(data = df4, aes(x = lon4, y = lat4,colour = "Pasture",fill = TRUE,alpha = 0.8), size = 8, shape = 16) +
  guides(fill=FALSE, alpha=FALSE, size=FALSE)
  geom_text(aes(label = state), data = mdat, size = 2, angle = 45)
```

[image: plot]